# Extracting ref and source tables from a dbt model

Tags: python, sql, dbt

I have a model in dbt which uses different sources and ref tables. So my question is...
Is it possible to create a macro that will extract all the ref and source tables from the model? Let me give you and example

I have this model:

```
    select
*

from        {{ ref('x') }}   a
left join   {{ source('landing', 'y') }} ma on a.... = ma....
left join   {{ source('landing', 'z') }} b on a.... = b....
```

So, once the macro is run for that model, I would like to get the names or the ref and source tables. Is that possible? I would like to do this in dbt, but let me know if it would be better to use python instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want a list of dependencies for a specific model? So like a list printing out x, y, and z?

Comment: Yess, please! thats what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- my_macro.sql

{% macro get_dependencies(model_name) %}
    {% set models = graph.nodes.values() %}

    {% set model = (models | selectattr('name', 'equalto', model_name) | list).pop() %}

    {% do log("sources: ", info=true) %}
    {% set sources = model['sources'] %}
    {% for source in sources %}
    {% do log(source[0] ~ '.' ~ source[1], info=true) %}
    {% endfor %}


    {% do log("refs: ", info=true) %}
    {% set refs = model['refs'] %}
    {% for ref in refs %}
    {% do log(ref[0], info=true) %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Once you add this macro, give it a try with this…

`dbt run-operation get_dependencies --args '{model_name: my_model}'`

and it will spit out…

```
sources:
landing.y
landing.z
refs:
x
```

The way I currently have it written, it will write out any repeating sources or models. e.g. if you have `{{ ref('x') }}` in multiple locations, then it will write it out as many times.

```
refs:
x
x
x
```

I used the below documentaiton about the graph variable to piece this together.

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/graph

EDIT:

Here's a way to get a unique list of sources and refs. It's not the prettiest but it works. (There has to be better way to get a unique list!)

```
{% macro get_dependencies(model_name) %}
    {% set models = graph.nodes.values() %}

    {% set model = (models | selectattr('name', 'equalto', model_name) | list).pop() %}
    {% set sources = model['sources'] %}
    {% set refs = model['refs'] %}


    {% do log("sources: ", info=true) %}
    {% set unique_sources = [] %}    
    {% for source in sources if source not in unique_sources %}
        {% do unique_sources.append(source) %}
        {% do log(source[0] ~ '.' ~ source[1], info=true) %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% do log("refs: ", info=true) %}
    {% set unique_refs = [] %}    
    {% for ref in refs if reference not in unique_refs %}
        {% do unique_refs.append(ref) %}
        {% do log(ref[0], info=true) %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}
```